# Dynamic dropdown value Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I am working on a Laravel application to do some simple data entry.

Course category is a CRUD with single text input field.

Awarding Body CRUD consists of few fields along with the Course Category field that gets populated from the database.

The Create, Read and Delete work well.

But when I edit/update the data in Awarding Body, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
> 'coursecategory' cannot be null (SQL: update `awarding_bodies` set
> `description` = Nebosh gdgd, `coursecategory` = ?, `validtill` =
> 2021-09-14, `awarding_bodies`.`updated_at` = 2021-09-07 12:56:30 where
> `id` = 1)

Can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?
PS. I am  new to Laravel & MVC frameworks.

Thanks in advance.

**edit method & update method**

```
public function AwardingBodyEdit($id) {
    $editData = AwardingBody::find($id);
    $coursecategories = CourseCatergory::all();
    return view('backend.setup.awarding_body.edit_awardingbody', compact('editData', 'coursecategories'));

}

public function AwardingBodyUpdate(Request $request, $id) {

    $data = AwardingBody::find($id);

    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->description = $request->description;
    $data->coursecategory = $request->coursecategory;
    $data->issuedate = $request->issuedate;
    $data->validtill = $request->validtill;
    $data->molapprovaldate = $request->molapprovaldate;
    $data->molvalidtilldate = $request->molvalidtilldate;
    $data->save();

    $notification = array (
        'message' => 'Awarding Body updated successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->route('awarding.body.view')->with($notification);
}
```

**My form**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('awarding.body.update', $editData->id) }}">
        @csrf
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">            
        
    <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
        <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Awarding Body Name<span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $editData->name }}" class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                </div>
                    @error('name')
                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
        </div>
    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
    <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Description <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                <div class="controls">
                <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="description" class="form-control" >{{ $editData->description }}</textarea>
                </div>
                    @error('name')
                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
    </div>
    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
    </div><!-- end row -->

    <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
    <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Course Category <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                <select name="coursecategory" class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                <option value="">{{ $editData->coursecategory }}</option>
                    @foreach($coursecategories as $coursecategory)
                    <option>{{$coursecategory->name}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
</select>
     </div>

    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
        
    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
    </div><!-- end row -->

    <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
    <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Issue Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" value="{{ $editData->issuedate }}" name="issuedate"  class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                </div>
                    @error('name')
                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
        </div>
    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
        <div class="form-group">
                <h5>Valid Till <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" value="{{ $editData->validtill }}" name="validtill"  class="form-control" >
                </div>
                    @error('name')
                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
        </div>
    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
    </div><!-- end row -->


    <div class="row"> <!-- start row -->
    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
        <div class="form-group">
                <h5>MOL Approval Issue Date <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" value="{{ $editData->molapprovaldate }}" name="molapprovaldate"  class="form-control" >
                </div>
                    @error('name')
                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
        </div>
    </div><!-- start col 6 -->

    <div class="col-md-6"> <!-- start col 6 -->
        <div class="form-group">
                <h5>MOL Approval Valid Till <span class="text-danger">*</span></h5>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" value="{{ $editData->molvalidtilldate }}" name="molvalidtilldate"  class="form-control" >
                </div>
                    @error('name')
                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                    @enderror
        </div>
    </div><!-- end col 6 -->
    </div><!-- end row -->



    <div class="text-xs-right">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded mb-5" value="Update">
    </div>
    </form>
```

**Routes:**

```
// Setup -> Awarding Body
Route::prefix('setup')->group(function(){
    Route::get('awarding_body/view', [AwardingBodyController::class, 'AwardingBodyView'])-> name('awarding.body.view'); 
    Route::get('awarding_body/add', [AwardingBodyController::class, 'AwardingBodyAdd'])-> name('awarding.body.add'); 
    Route::post('awarding_body/store', [AwardingBodyController::class, 'AwardingBodyStore'])-> name('awarding.body.store'); 
    Route::get('awarding_body/edit/{id}', [AwardingBodyController::class, 'AwardingBodyEdit'])-> name('awarding.body.edit'); 
    Route::post('awarding_body/update/{id}', [AwardingBodyController::class, 'AwardingBodyUpdate'])-> name('awarding.body.update'); 
    Route::get('awarding_body/delete/{id}', [AwardingBodyController::class, 'AwardingBodyDelete'])-> name('awarding.body.delete'); 
});
```

Comment: you're populating the dropdown's options for `coursecategory` without any values.

Comment: @jade i need to get my eyesight tested!! that was way too silly of me.
Thanks a ton for the pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by @jade, i was populating dropdown list without values.

```
            <option value="{{ $editData->coursecategory }}">{{ $editData->coursecategory }}</option>
```